# Is there a way to get the PE ratio from Python's yfinance module?

Tags: python, yfinance

I would like to get the PE ratio from yfinance.

```
import yfinance as yf

symbol = yf.Ticker('msft').info
print(symbol['pe_ratio'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two available ones in `yfinance` are `trailingPE` and `forwardPE`. To obtain them:

```py
import yfinance as yf

symbol = yf.Ticker("msft").info
symbol["trailingPE"]
symbol["forwardPE"]
```

Comment: There is no way to obtain historical P/E values, correct? The yfinance library only provides the current values if I'm not mistaken. It is of course not a big issue to calculate the values, but no need to reinvent the wheel if it is already available.